# How do you add more than one phone number on iMessage?

Tags: ios, icloud, messages, apple-id

My sisters and I all have iPhones under the same account. I also have an iPad under the same account. I am trying to get the iMessage on my iPad compatible with my phone number, not email address.

The only phone number choice to choose from is my sister's iPhone number. **How can I choose my phone number for iMessage on my iPad?**

Answer (score 6):

The only way to get a phone number associated with iMessage is for that phone number to be provisioned to an iPhone and have SMS messages active from the carrier. At that point, you can sign in to iMessage with your Apple ID / iCloud account and it will verify the phone number is actually connected to that device and your AppleID will then inherit that phone number.

At that point, you can remove that phone number from that iPhone and use another Apple ID with iMessage. With dual sim / esim you might even get both numbers active on one iOS device.

So, unless you can borrow an iPhone long enough to get your carrier to provide 5 minutes of service to an iPhone - long enough to register, you will be stuck with an email address for iMessage.

By this process, you could have more than one phone number associated with one Apple ID. You cannot however get one phone number associated with more than one Apple ID as the last ID to get registered with iMessage removes that number from any other Apple ID that used to "claim" that number as deliverable.

Comment: It only gives me the choice of my sisters number! I don't know how to add another phone number!

Comment: You can only associate one phone number to any Apple ID as far as I know, so having seperate Apple IDs would be the preferred way to go.

Comment: While I agree separate Apple IDs are the preferred way to go, you can actually have multiple phone numbers on the same Apple ID. In my case, I have two iPhones, one on Verizon and one on AT&T.  When I signed into my iCloud account on each, each number was added to my account.  Now both numbers are associated with my account.

Comment: What if i have ONE iPhone with 2 SIMs? (one regular sim, one eSim). Can't add the other number.

Answer (score 4):

It appears the crucial point is you have **two iPhones**, so both SIMs registered to your iCloud/iMessage at the same time.

If you only have one iPhone and two SIM cards, taking the first SIM out and using the second SIM will deactivate the first SIM mobile number from iMessage.

Comment: I have two iPhones: an iPhone 6 and an iPhone X, with two different SIMs in them, but only my iPhone X number appears in the "I can be reached at..." list in Settings on my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second iPhone phone number to an iPad - you sign into the second iPhone with your Apple ID and the go to iMessage and select 'use iMessage with my Apple ID'.  The phone number of the second iPhone will appear on the iPad.

Comment: Yup! ...and on all of your other devices with that iCloud account too. I'm doing exactly that myself. I have two iPhones (one AT&T, one Verizon), a Mac Pro, MacBook Pro and MacBook Retina. All seven devices show both numbers and I can switch between all of them effortlessly.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add another phone number to the same Apple ID, but you can add another e-mail address instead.

Go to *Settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive* and '*Add Another E-mail...*' there.

Comment: Not true. I have two iPhones, one on AT&T and one on Verizon, both sharing the same Apple ID. Both numbers show up under my Messages setting on both phones, and for the matter, on all of my other devices which are also signed in (i.e. two iPads and three Macs.)

Comment: @MarqueIV You can share iMessage with multiple devices, but you can't associate two separate phone numbers into one Apple ID.

Comment: Again, you're wrong.  I just told you I've done exactly that.  I have both my Verizon phone number and my AT&T phone number assigned to the same Apple ID.

Comment: @MarqueIV So where you can add an extra number? In iMessage it allows you to add only the e-mail.

Comment: You don't add it from iMessage.  When you add your Apple ID to each phone, it associates that phone number with the account.  So when I first signed in with my Apple ID on my Verizon iPhone, that number was associated.  Then when I did the same with my AT&T iPhone, that number too was associated with the account.

Comment: @MarqueIV I'll have a look, thanks. If you know the solution, you can provide your own answer then.

Comment: Someone already posted that as an answer so I'd just be repeating it.

Comment: Just clarifying one thing... when you sign in to iCloud on each phone, you also have to explicitly say to use that phone with iMessage.  Simply signing into iCloud is not enough if you don't also enable iMessage.  Also, under the 'I can be reached at' portion of the settings, you'll notice you can't uncheck that particular device's phone number.  So my AT&t device *has* to receive iMessages from AT&T but can also receive them from the Verizon number (provided someone is sending an iMessage of course.)